# Is there a way to animate a sprite partially in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I plan on animating my 2D characters in unity
However, their actions are multi-dimensional, so they could, as an example, be walking at the same time as looking up or firing their gun, each animation would target one part of the sprites and if possible be independent.

the sprite sheet would be far too big to present every possible animation combination,
so is there a way to animate parts of a sprite individually?

Comment: That sounds like you want to use the 2D animation package: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.animation@2.2/manual/index.html

Comment: That seems like a good package. 
It also seems to support sprite swapping which would be important for me.
Post it as an answer so I can accept it plz :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an official Unity Package which supports 2D character rigging and other advanced features such as sprite swapping: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.animation@2.2/manual/index.html

Be aware that it is still marked as being in preview

Comment: In preview is better than nothing ahah

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating the parts you want to move independently as separate gameobjects. Then use the buit-in animator to create your aminations or use scripts to transform/translate/rotate parts.